# Chrome extension onConnect listener fires more than once from different tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension that works with this structure of .js files:

Page A (content script) -> B (background script) -> Page C (content script)

On page A, there are links that, when clicked, send a message to B. The idea of B is to open up a new tab and load page C; when C is fully loaded, it'll send a message back to B, which will send some data to C to fill in a form.

This all works, but after putting in some logging I realized that my listeners in B are actually firing twice if more than one link is clicked from page A. Here's what the code looks like:

Page A:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.click-test').click(function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({formData: here}, function(response) {
    });
  });
});
```

B:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
      console.assert(port.name == "formStatus");
      port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.status == "formReady") {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {formData: here}, function(response) {
                // The below is being called twice incorrectly if two links from page A are clicked
                console.log("sent message for tab ID " + tabs[0].id);
              });
            });
        }
      });
    });
    chrome.tabs.create({url: requestFormUrl});
});
```

Page C:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      // Fill in form with request data    
  });
  var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "formStatus"});
  port.postMessage({status: "formReady"});
});
```

When the first link on page A is clicked, things work fine. When the second link is clicked, the onConnect listener in B fires twice: first with the same data as the first click, then with the correct data corresponding to the second click.

Is there some way to disable B's listener as soon as it fires once? Or, have I just made this code way too complicated?

Comment: Your messaging logic is flawed. I don't have the time to try and fix your full logic, but the reason for getting multiple onConnect calls is that you're registering a new event listener for every onMessage call. To fix this, unregister the onConnect message listener upon receiving a connection, using `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function listener(port) {chrome.runtime.onConnect.removeListener(listener);` .

Answer (score 0):

Rob W. is right in the comments - removing the listener as he did within the addListener part worked. Thanks!